# Media Queries-Why is the css code that sould be executed not excuting

Tags: css, media-queries

So here is the css code and when i go to developer tools (Mozila) the code isn`t executed in responisve mode as it should.
The margin-left:auto; is underlined as u can see in the picture that i uploaded.
I am new to responsive design.If you wanna see the whole project(page) click [here](https://codepen.io/DrakeApplewood/pen/jwBBRw), please help.

[Developer tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26bEl.png)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    img {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
}
img {
    margin-left: 40%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
small {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 45%;
}
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 0.1em solid #4d4d4d;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 0;
}
#title {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
#content {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
#e {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#timeline {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#sources {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
#Author {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of declarations in CSS matters. Move the media query BELOW the `img { margin-left:40%; }` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The media queries you see in style sheets tend to be better placed at the bottom. Place

```
    @media screen and (max-width:750px){
 img{
   margin-left:auto;
  }
}
```

underneath the last CSS declaration